# How to populate any array from negative to positive number from two number?

Tags: javascript

How can I populate an array from negative to positive numbers like:

> numbers['-3','-2.5','-2','1.5','1','0.5','0.0','+0.5','+1','+1.5','+2','+2.5','+3','+3.5','+4','+4.5','+5'];

from `minnumber` and `maxnumber`

```
var minnumber = 3;
var maxnumber = 5;

var numbers = [];

numbers['-3','-2.5','-2','1.5','1','0.5','0.0','+0.5','+1','+1.5','+2','+2.5','+3','+3.5','+4','+4.5','+5']
```

Comment: Surely you tried something you could have shown us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through many ways, below I have used `Array.from`

```js
var minnumber = 3;
var maxnumber = 5;

var numbers = Array.from({ length: (maxnumber + minnumber) * 2 + 1}, (_,i) => (-minnumber + i * 0.5).toString())

console.log(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate from the min number to the max number using a step of 0.5.

Based on your example it also looks like you want to convert the numbers to strings.

```js
const min = -3;
const max = 5;
const step = 0.5;
const arr = [];

for (let i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
  const str = (i).toString();

   // if you want to push the number to the
   // array instead remove the preceding line
   // and just use arr.push(i)
   arr.push(str);
}

console.log(arr);
```